# Typing special characters (using Alt Gr) in NetBeans / Java

Tags: java, netbeans, x11

I'm using Serbian Latin keyboard on CentOS 6.1. When I press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> I get }. Everywhere, except in NetBeans.

Also, I'm unable to type any bracket []{} or \|. Did anyone come across solution to this?

Changing keyboard for every brace or other symbol is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install Sun/Oracle Java, and reinstall NetBEans.

Answer (score 1):

actually it is an X11/distro bug.

KDE or GTK apps use their own keyboard mechanism, so they don't show that problem;
but java (and thus, netbeans) use the X11 keyboard mechanism for input.

The problem is in how X11 handles your locale; if set properly it works; if not it doesn't.
X11 doesn't has any "default" rule; if your locale isn't know to X11, you have nothing.
Also, X11 locales support isn't much updated either.

X11, in order to allow proper altgr/compose rules has to load a proper "Compose" file.
It loads it (or not) depending on the locale: in a /usr/share/X11/locale/compose.dir file (your path may vary) there are lines like:

```
en_US.UTF-8/Compose             en_US.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8/Compose             sr_CS.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8/Compose:            en_US.UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8/Compose:            sr_CS.UTF-8
```

etc.
(yes, two lines per locale, with and without colon; one is used by old programs, other by new ones; but I don't remember which is which)

there must be a line for the locale you use (shown with "locale" command).
Note that if the system uses locales like "en_US.utf8" there must be an alias
(in the locales.alias file); something like:

```
sr_CS.utf8     sr_CS.UTF-8
...
sr_CS.utf8:    sr_CS.UTF-8
```

(again, duplicate with and without colon)

To solve your problem, you can either set LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 before launching java programs; or edit (you need to be root, and do it at each X11 update) the compose.dir (and locale.dir and/or locale.alias) files, copy the en_US.UTF-8 lines and adapt to your locale.
You can also report to your distro so they patch those *.dir/*.alias files to work properly for all locales provided by the distro.